# How do you compress your response with express.js?

Tags: javascript, express, compression

I am currently using the latest [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and [compression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression). I am reading a text file and returning it with compression enabled.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
var compression = require('compression')

app.use(compression())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var fs = require('fs')
    fs.readFile('./test.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(data)
    });
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

The app reads and return the text content properly when I pass the header `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`. Even though the response headers says the response is `Content-Encoding: gzip`, the size is similar to the size of the text file. Am I missing anything to compress the response properly?

Comment: What's in the text file? It's possible that gzip just doesn't compress it that much.

Comment: 100 paragraphs of generated text from https://loremipsum.io/generator/?n=100&t=p. The size is a lot more than the default threshold of 1kb.

Comment: 1) "_the size is similar to the size of the text file_" exact numbers please. 2) and what if you try with more easily compressible text, like a string of a single repeating character? 3) what if you pass a higher [compression `level` parameter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression#level) to the middleware?

Comment: A 300kb file of text or json with level 9 compression gave me similar size after I called the endpoint through postman with the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` in the request header.

Comment: okay that answers question 3 without answering question 1 or 2 :/

Comment: 4) and when you say the size is similar, what number are you looking at? In your browser's network tab, it should show two numbers. Ex. in Chrome, one for "transferred over network" (relating to the compressed size), and one for "resource size" (relating to uncompressed size). What number are you comparing with?

Comment: File size was 312kb, compressed was 305kb with default compression or level 9 compression. I also tried repeated characters, the behaviour is the same.

Comment: "_File size was 312kb, compressed was 305kb_" for what compression level?

Comment: I have done similar response compression with other web frameworks such as fastapi. With fastapi, I can compress a 300kb json into 10kb. I could not reproduce that with expressjs for the same json.

Comment: your question post mentions _**nothing**_ about postman. please provide enough detail in the question for people to actually be able to answer the question just given the info in the question post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is an [existing bug](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7596) in the latest Postman as of May 1st, 2023 that does not show the compressed response size when it is returned from nodejs. When I use the Insomnia app, I can see the compressed response size for the same code.